# Perl WWW::Mechanize -- Authentication Error GETing URL

Tags: perl, webforms, mechanize, www-mechanize

I'm trying to fill out a web form using the Mechanize library of Perl.

Whenever I enter the URL into the search box it prompts the below message, and I can manually login sucessfully.

[image]

However, when I run the below script, I get the following error:

[image]

How do I correctly fill in the first Authentication Box credentials using my `$mech` object?

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( 'keepalive' => 1 );

my $url = "http://URL/I/NEED/TO/ACCESS";
my $username = "username";
my $password = "password";

$mech->credentials($username, $password);
$mech->get($url);          <----------------- ERROR (LINE 93)
```

**EDIT:**

Here are the results of running `wget` on the requested site

```
--2013-08-30 11:16:17--  http://moss.micron.com/MFG/ProbeTest/Lists/Manufacturing%20Requests/AllItems.aspx
Resolving moss.micron.com... 137.201.88.118
Connecting to moss.micron.com|137.201.88.118|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
  WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
  WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6341
  Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2013 17:16:17 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Length: 0
Authorization failed.
```

Comment: What version of Mechanize are you using?

Comment: How can I check the current version?

Comment: Just checked. I'm using VERSION 1.70

Comment: Should be new enough. Your code works just fine for me. I noticed that your user and password are in double quotes. Is there a `$` or some other control character in your user or password? If so, try single quotes.

Comment: Nope, just a '\' in my username for the domain separator. Can you give  me the URL link you're using, so I can also test? Thanks

Comment: A \ will have the effect of escaping the following character. Change it to single quotes or use \\.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With older versions of Mechanize you could subclass the [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3A%3AMechanize) package and provide your own credentials routine:

```
package MyMech;

use vars qw(@ISA);
@ISA = qw(WWW::Mechanize);

sub get_basic_credentials {
  my ($self, $realm, $uri) = @_;
  return( "user", "password" );
}
```

Then in your program use this package instead of WWW::Mechanize:

```
package main;

my $mech = MyMech->new();
$mech->get( $url );
```

**Update**

You've updated your question to indicate the requirement of NTLM authentication. Check out [LWP::Authen::Ntlm](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/Authen/Ntlm.pm) on CPAN.

Comment: What's wrong with the default credentials routine? It looks to be the same as the one you're suggesting to override

Comment: I no longer get the connection error, but it doesn't seem like the Mech agent is properly GETing the webpage. Even if I remove the `get_basic_credentials` sub routine, it seemingly allows me to get the url (which is suspicious). Also, nothing shows up when I try to dump the forms in  $mech->forms

Comment: @user1022944 nothing wrong with the default credentials routine. But years ago I started using this pattern which would work when other techniques failed. Also note this works with HTTP Basic Auth, not Digest Auth. As part of your question I recommend you run wget and paste a copy of the output (so we can see the headers from your website): `wget -O /dev/null -S http://www.bbc.co.uk/` (but substitute BBC for the URL you are fetching).

Comment: I've run `wget` on the page. What do you make of the headers?

Comment: @user1022944 Your web server requires `NTLM` authentication, not `Basic`. See http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/authentication.html#Authentication_Schemes for a description of the difference.