# Python mechanize form authentication error

Tags: python, authentication, forms-authentication, mechanize

I'm trying to automate form filling on Sharepoint site, but my Python script can't get passed this authentication box that pops up when you type in the url from below.

[image: Auth Box]

```
from base64 import b64encode
import mechanize

url = 'http://moss.micron.com/MFG/ProbeTest/Lists/Manufacturing%20Requests/AllItems.aspx'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

# I have had to add a carriage return ('%s:%s\n'), but
# you may not have to.
b64login = b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))

br = mechanize.Browser()

br.addheaders.append( 
  ('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % b64login,  )
)

br.open(url)!
```

This results in the following error:

[image: Error]

**EDIT:**

Here are the results of running `wget` on the requested page.

```
--2013-08-30 11:16:17--  http://moss.micron.com/MFG/ProbeTest/Lists/Manufacturing%20Requests/AllItems.aspx
Resolving moss.micron.com... 137.201.88.118
Connecting to moss.micron.com|137.201.88.118|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
  WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
  WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 12.0.0.6341
  Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2013 17:16:17 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Length: 0
Authorization failed.
```

Comment: Please use error output, i.e. text, not screenshot for text error output...

Comment: @Mark Kennedy, did you manage to solve this issue? I am facing the exact same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is respecting the robots.txt on your site disallowing it.

You can set mechanize.Browser to ignore robots.txt, prior to making the request via:
`br.set_handle_robots(False)`

Alternately, edit your robots.txt to allow that sort of connection.

If you set a custom UserAgent header in your mechanize.Browser to allow you to filter for it.

See [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) for basic info about robots.txt.

Comment: After making that change I get a new error: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Comment: I am certain my username/password combination is correct. Is this because I'm trying to connect to a Sharepoint site?

Comment: I presume it does have some sort of filtering against browsers attempting to access it without a UserAgent header.

Comment: Maybe try using the built in function for http auth?

```br.add_password('http://safe-site.domain', 'username', 'password')```

Comment: @DivinuxVox I already tried that before. I also tried adding the following. Still get the same error `br.addheaders(['User-agent', 'Mozilla/20.0)')]`

Comment: @user1022944 Hmmm not 100%, I'll have to play with it a bit later when I have access to a server to test auth against.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue in Perl here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889817/perl-wwwmechanize-authentication-error-geting-url[/link]

Answer (score 0):

If you can get to the site with a PC, download Fiddler2 which will allow you to see the transactions required when you log in.

Edit.. Ok. Obviously you have a PC.

Comment: I've run a `wget` command. The WWW-Authenticate values seem to jump at me.